# WP Ajax Function Always Returning undefined

Tags: functions, ajax, jquery

What is the deal here?

> JS FUNCTION 'custom.js'

```
function validate() {
    var email = jQuery("#billingemail").val();

    if (isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "custome_ajax_email_check", "guestemail": email },
            success: function(data){
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.result) {
                    alert('Email Exists');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    alert('Email Does Exists');
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> JS ON CLICK 'custom.js'

```
 $('#mwb_logincoupon').on('click', '#validateguestemail', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validateemail = validate();
```

> PHP AJAX

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custome_ajax_email_check', 'custome_ajax_email_check' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custome_ajax_email_check', 'custome_ajax_email_check');

function custome_ajax_email_check(){
    $email = $_POST['guestemail'];

    // do check
    if ( email_exists($email) ) {
        $response->result = true;
    }
    else {
        $response->result = false;
    }

    echo( json_encode( $response));
    wp_die();
}
```

debugging the script the JS code goes into the `success` function, so far as even triggering off the `alert('Email Exists')`.. but the `return` statement in the functon is never retrieved thus making `validateemail` always return `undefined`. Why?

Comment: Nevermind, I just took it out of the `validate()` function and just put it inline with the rest of the code and it works fine.. why can you not return values in functions like this?

Comment: That's a question you should ask on Stack Overflow, but you should use the [`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) keyword if you want the `validate()` function to resolve to the return value of your AJAX's `success()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Per @SallyCJ suggestion to use `await` I construed this new function

```
async function doAjax(email) {
    let result;

    try {
        result = await jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"action": "custome_ajax_email_check", "guestemail": email }
        });

        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Then my `validate()` function now just is simply

```
function validate() {
    var email = jQuery("#billingemail").val();

    if (isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
        doAjax(email).then( (data) => ajaxCallResult(data) )
    }

  . . . . .
```

Then lastly

```
function ajaxCallResult(data){

    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 
  . . . . . .
```

It is working.. very interesting, learning about `await` `then`, `asynchronous` and `synchronous` calls, etc